# Why is my browser showing a blank page after code splitting node modules with webpack?

Tags: webpack

I am trying to optimize my site's speed performance by splitting code with webpack, specifically my node modules, with each module split into its own bundle.

The bundle splitting works fine for our own code base, but when I split the node modules, the browser shows a blank page with no error. The main bundle is successfully fetched but doesn't seem to execute properly.

This is my webpack config file:

```js
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/public/js');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/js');
var CSS_DIR = path.resolve(APP_DIR, 'css');

var config_function = function(env){
  var config = {
    mode: env && env.prod ? 'production':'development',
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', APP_DIR + '/index.js'],
    output: {
      path: BUILD_DIR,
      filename: env && env.prod ? '[name].bundle.min.js' : '[name].bundle.js',
      publicPath: '/static/js/'
    },
    optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: 'single',
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all',
            maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
            minSize: 0,
            cacheGroups:{
                vendor: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name(module) {
                        const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1];
                        return `npm.${packageName.replace('@', '')}`;
                    },
                }
            }
        }
    },
    plugins: env && env.prod ? [
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
             'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"'
         }),
        new UglifyJSPlugin({uglifyOptions:{
            ecma: 5,
            mangle: {
                safari10: true
            },
            warnings: false,
            screw_ie8: true,
            compress: true,
        }}),
        new CompressionPlugin({
            algorithm: 'gzip',
            minRatio: 1})
    ]: [
        new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
    ],
    module: {
      rules: [{
        test: /\.jsx?/,
        include: [APP_DIR, /node_modules\/snakecase-keys/, /node_modules\/redux-api-middleware/,/node_modules\/map-obj/, /node_modules\/hare-niemeyer/, /node_modules\/round-to/, /node_modules\/styled-components/],
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-2'], //, 'react-hmre']
          plugins: ['recharts']
        }
      }, {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      }, {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader',
        type: 'javascript/auto'
      }, {
        test: /\.less$/,
        include: CSS_DIR,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader']
      }, {
          test: /\.css$/,
          loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }, {
          test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
          loader: 'url-loader'
      },
    ]
    }
  };

  return config;
}

module.exports = config_function;
```

The code splitting looks exactly as I expected it to be : each npm package has its own bundle and the rest of our own code is also successfully split. It just doesn't execute as expected however (i.e. blank page with no error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I misunderstood the technology and thought the runtime bundle was responsible for dynamically fetching the individual npm modules.

Had to fetch each individual npm module via a script in my index.html file to make it work.